# Removing the device partnership in Exchange 2010 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to create a script that will remove the mobile phone partnership from a user in Exchange 2010.  My plan of implementation was to use Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics to find the identity of the mobile device then use Remove-ActiveSyncDevice to remove it.  However, I cant seem to get the identity into a variable.  I've tried 2 methods that done seem to work which are

Method 1:

```
$UserMailbox = Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox R68Fred
Remove-ActiveSyncDevice -Identity $UserMailbox.identity -Confirm $true
```

Method 2:

```
Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics -Mailbox R68Fred | Select-Object -Property "Identity"
```

I'm still fairly new to Powershell so I dont know if my plan of attack is correct so I appreciate any advice in the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead use [`Get-ActiveSyncDevice`](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/06a82fdc-9bf7-43c7-8471-d977034d3560(EXCHG.141).aspx) cmdlet, this gets you the device identity. You can still filter on `Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics` to get only those devices that are deemed inactive based on say `LastSuccessSync` property.